# Elasticsearch: wildcard space key detection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, elasticsearch

I want to search in elasticsearch just like in sql server. This is the query i want to do.

select * from products where name like '%samsung a50%'

I can do this query with the following c# code.

c#:

```
  var urunler = elasticClient.Search<Urun>
      (s => s.From(0)
       .Query(query => query.Bool(b => b.Must(
        x => x.Wildcard(x => x.Field("ad").Value("*" + value + "*"))
          )))).Documents.ToList();
```

but it does not query if there is a space between the words. For example, if I search for the word "samsung", it finds it. but it doesn't find the word "samsung a50". because there is a space between "samsung" and "a50". I want it to find even if there is space. how can I do it? please show with c# codes.

It should also be able to filter the moment I press the letter like it is now. It should also be able to detect the spacebar. And of course, there should be capitalization as well.

Comment: just run a .contains()?  That would return "samsung" and "samsung a50", and "samsung thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog a50", and "my favorite samsung a50"... etc...

Comment: @pcalkins I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to solving your problem is to set the accuracy of fuzzy query. As the following code:

```
Fuzziness.AutoLength(1, 2)
```

`Fuzziness.AutoLength(1, 2)` The minimum value of the specified editing distance is 1, and the maximum value is 2. This means that Elasticsearch will try to match the query string with at least 1 character but not more than 2 characters.

You can adjust accuracy according to your actual needs.

[image]

```
    public IList<ArticleModel> GetSearch(string keyword)
    {

        var result = _elasticClient.Search<ArticleModel>(s => s.From(0)

        .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Title)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.AutoLength(1, 2))
                    .Query(keyword)
                )
        )

        ).Documents.ToList();

        var finalContent = result;
        return finalContent;
    }
```

---

`Match` and `Fuzziness` to perform fuzzy searches that match words with spaces should be the best solution.

**Sample**

```
var urunler = _elasticClient.Search<Urun>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(
                m => m.Match(mt => mt
                    .Field("ad")
                    .Query(value)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                )
            )
        )
    )
).Documents.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't bring the product even when typing the word. For example, when I type "sam" in the other, "samsung" products appear. but it doesn't bring the name "samsung" without writing it in full. how can i do it